# How to use get_user() to send data from user space to kernel space?

Tags: linux, kernel, communication, userspace

I have calculated the value of a parameter in user space and would like to pass the integer value to kernel space. I know that I have to use `get_user(x, ptr)`, but I'm not sure how to provide the pointer to the kernel module.

I have an integer variable in my user space code and I can find the pointer to it. However, I should know the pointer beforehand so that I can use it in my kernel code. Do I need to allocate a specific memory location (i.e. 0x...) to the integer variable so that I can use it in both codes or there's another workaround?

I want this data transfer to have the minimum possible overhead.

Comment: What system call are you using to get to that `get_user` call?  That's the key to know how to pass user info to kernel.  User and kernel spaces use different virtual address spaces, so that's the reason of havin `copy_to_user()` and `copy_from_user()` functions.  Please **edit your question** showing some code or explaining how did you get executing kernel code from user space if not a system call.

Comment: I'm trying to create an entry in /proc and read its contents from user space and execute `get_user` there. I'm stuck in creating the entry for now. I'll update my question soon.

Comment: ok, so you are going to pass the information via read(2) system call in text format, right?

Comment: I created the /proc entry and I'm doing `cat myproc` to test the read operation. It works with copy_to_user but not with put_user

Comment: How did you create an entry in `/proc`?  Are you programming in kernel side or in user side?  What's the problem with using `copy_to_user` instead of `put_user`?

Comment: I kinda figured out how to solve this problem. I created a proc entry in my kernel module and defined my read and write functions. Then, I call `put_user` and `get_user` in read and write functions, respectively. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: So perhaps I have helped you without even have to write a response... :)